# How do I create a conditional unique constraint across multiple tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, constraints, unique-constraint

I'm working on a web application using Hibernate 4 and Oracle 11g.

I have the following tables that I'm working with in this scenario.  Tables have been changed and simplified to protect the innocent.

```
entry
ID  |   name    |
1   |   thing1  |
2   |   thing2  |

entry_number
ID  |   value   |   entry_id|   type_id |
1   |   11111   |   1       |   1       |
2   |   22222   |   1       |   2       |
3   |   33333   |   1       |   2       |
4   |   aaaaa   |   2       |   1       |
5   |   bbbbb   |   2       |   2       |
6   |   ccccc   |   2       |   2       |

type
ID  |   name    |
1   |   unique  |
2   |   regular |
3   |   etc.    |
...
```

The idea is that I want to conditionally restrict insertions of entry_number so that there can only be one number of type "unique" assigned to any given entry.  Unfortunately, many of the straightforward constraint approaches don't work for this scenario.  After some research, I've found the following solution works:

```
create unique index unique_entry_number on entry_number(CASE WHEN TYPE_ID = 1 THEN entry_id ELSE null END);
```

The only thing I don't like about this is that I am referencing the id for "type_id", which I don't believe I can necessarily depend on to be consistent.  And Oracle won't let me use a subquery inside of the unique index to join on "type.name" which I can depend on to be consistent.

Is there a different approach I should use that I'm not aware of or are there any suggestions on how I might mitigate this problem?  Preferably one that is as un-intrusive as possible in respect to code changes or data model changes?  Or is this just a reality I will have to learn to deal with?

Comment: What is this `item_number` you talk about? I don't see it in your data model.

Comment: The "uniqueness" you want to achieve sounds like something that does not naturally belong as a constraint in your relational database, but like something that should be enforced in your code/UI.

Comment: @KlausByskovPedersen Sorry, I made some changes party way through my post and forgot to change in some places.  I edited it to be consistent.

Comment: +1. Good question. I think it's "just a reality [you] will have to learn to deal with", but I'm interested to see what people suggest.

Comment: @KlausByskovPedersen It's important that the uniqueness be enforced, so making it a constraint on the database will ensure that code changes or SQL statements made later will not accidentally violate this.  If it's done only in code, then it allows too much opportunity for mistakes violating this uniqueness.

Comment: Constraints of this nature are usually enforced with triggers or by mandating data access via stored procedures instead of direct DML statements issued by the application.

Comment: @mustaccio: the index *does* enforce this constraints, the drawback is (and that's Blue_Helix's question) that the `type_id` is hardcoded in the constraint, whereas it would be better to use `unique` in there.

Comment: @Blue_Helix: another option would be to get rid of the artificial primary key of the `type` table and use the `name` column as the PK for that. Then your `item_number` will actually contain the value `'unique'  as a reference to the `type` table and the partial unique index will not have to hardcode that `type_id`. The values don't seem to be getting too large in order to have a noticeable effect on size and performance in the `item_number` table (but you should test).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name -- so it can _not_ enforce this particular constraint, because it requires a lookup.

Comment: @mustaccio: depends on what you understand with "not enforce". Given the sample data, this constraint **is** enforced. But once the value for `type_id = 1` is changed to something else than `unique` then it's no longer enforced, that's correct.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name -- the requirement, as I understood it, was to enforce the uniqueness of "unique", not of "1". The chosen data model does not allow that, not by using a unique index anyway.

Comment: if the unique constraint doesn't work for you, have u considered a before insert/update trigger?  Not a huge fan of triggers, but may be more flexible for your situation.  You could lookup in type table to find value for 'unique' also.  Just a thought

Comment: @tbone Yeah, I read a bit about triggers after you mentioned it.  But from what I've read, it seems like triggers can be a scary road to go down, to be avoided if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that you can have a check constraint on a materialized view; so, you should be able to write something like this:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG
    ON entry_number
    WITH ROWID
;
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG
    ON type
    WITH ROWID
;
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW entry_number_counter
    REFRESH FAST
    ON COMMIT
    AS SELECT en.entry_id, COUNT(1) AS row_count
           FROM entry_number en
           JOIN type ON entry_number.type_id = type.id
           WHERE type.name = 'unique'
           GROUP BY en.entry_id, type.name
;
ALTER TABLE entry_number_counter
    ADD CONSTRAINT entry_id_conditionally_unique
       CHECK (row_count = 1)
;
```

(Disclaimer: not tested. This is adapted from an example in [Tom Kyte's "The Trouble With Triggers"](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-sep/o58asktom-101055.html). If you decide to go this route, you'll want to read through the documentation first and understand all of it; in particular, I'm not very clear on the "materialized view log" part, and it may need some adjustments.)

Comment: I had to make a few changes to make it work, but this looks like it may be promising. Point of concern, however, is space and performance. From what I've read, the log is there largely for performance (like a cache) to enable the "fast refresh" so it doesn't have to refresh a bunch of data at once. My reading also seems to indicate that it is fine for large amounts of data, but when I look at the materialized view table with a small sample set, there are almost as many rows as the entry table. That's worrying because the real world "entry" table is very large.  Should I be worried?

Comment: @Blue_Helix: I've edited the answer to make the materialized view smaller. But even so -- yes, this is a serious tradeoff. Since it sounds like your `type` table is more or less fixed, it's probably easier to just add a normal functional index as you originally planned, and just accept the fact that your index will have to be created after you populate `type`.

Comment: @Blue_Helix You can add a condition to the MATERIALIZED VIEW definition that filters out the undesired items: `HAVING count(1)!=1` This way the materialized view will have 0 rows.

Comment: @Blue_Helix The HAVING clause apparently conflicts with FAST REFRESH, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/38779462/822870

Answer (score 0):

You may use compound triggers in Oracle to ensure uniqueness across several tables.
This post describes how to implement the check at DML level.
https://rammpeter.blogspot.com/2023/08/oracle-db-ensure-uniqueness-across.html?m=1